# Need help getting line to "draw" in python (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

ive been following a tutorial to learn pygame. the code below is to make a window (640 by 400) that s green. The program is also exposed to draw a red line across the screen. so far i have not been sucessfull in having the line appear. any suggestions?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400))
running = 1
green = 0, 255, 0
red = 255, 0, 0
point1 = 639, 479
point2 = 0, 0


while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = 0

    screen.fill(green)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.draw.line(screen, red, point1, point2)
```

Comment: When asking for help with a problem, it is helpful to be specific about what in particular isn't working and what error message if any you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call draw.line before the display.flip(), as it is now you are copying the data from the buffer to the display before the lines is drawn.

Comment: +1; put the `flip()` call at the very end of the loop; you almost always want it there.

Answer (score 0):

in order for some functions to work you have to change your code at the beginning to:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
```

this makes sure you have all of the essentials and that you "initialize" pygame.
without pygame.init() it wouldn't "turn on" most of the functions